# Problems Finding In The Correct Derivative

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble to find the correct derivative of a function....

The Function :

$$
f(x) = x^3 \cdot \frac{\sin x}{e^x}
$$

When I tried to find out the derivative answer manually, I found This:
[image: answer]

Now, I was trying to make some tests.....

Suppose ,When i put x=3 in the answer, I found the result = 1.342408597
But when i used scientific calculator to find the answer I found the result : 0.02342944992
I didn't understand what happened..
You can use your Casio fx-ES calculator to see the result. Use The Calculator d/dx function to check it....
Then i was tying to find the connection between these two numbers....
I found: 1.342408597/0.02342944992 = 1 radian = 180/pi
Can anyone tell me, why calculator is saying such result?

Comment: I don't see what you were trying to achieve by putting in $x=3$ ... However, I think the derivative expression that you calculated is correct.

Comment: If $x$ is in degrees, then $f'(3) \approx 1.342~409$ (your first result). If $x$ is in radians (the default option on my opinion) then $f'(3) \approx -1.330~798$.

Comment: Matlab says the answer is $-1.3308$, assuming your formula for the derivative is correct. In any case, the slope at $x=3$ is negative, as you can see by plotting $f(x)$. So neither of your numerical results is correct.